# Chrome and Chromium cannot open web page over HTTP

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have this problem for a couple of days now. Both Chrome and Chromium fail to get any content through http. Basically, the whole page content area below the address bar and bookmarks stays blank, the tab title stays as "loading" and the icon on the left keep making circle to show loading is happening... but nothing gets displayed. However, Firefox works fine when trying to open the same web page that chrome/chromium fail to open. Also, chrome and chromium succeed in opening a local html file.

I can fix the problem by deleting `~/.config/chromium` (`~/.config/google-chrome` for chrome) and then both browsers work again as expected, but not for long. I can't be certain, but I am under the impression that both fails to work again as soon as I open a new gnome session.

I don't know where to look. I use Ubuntu 17.10, with nothing really fancy or known for being troublesome (except perhaps the use of nvidia drivers, skype and docker-ce but I don't expect them to cause this particular trouble). Do you have any idea on where I should look?

EDIT 1:
I don't have any proxy defined that gnome-control-center shows
Output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show`

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:F7:A2:A0:EB
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp59s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:28:F8:36:AC:09
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     SKY3B380
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.89/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          Home
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a02:c7d:51b5:ee00:b15f:19c8:6776:19d0/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fd36:554f:9232:0:b15f:19c8:6776:19d0/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         2a02:c7d:51b5:ee00:9d56:72d1:7c87:4ff7/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         fd36:554f:9232:0:89ce:9a12:8a4f:9bc9/64
IP6.ADDRESS[5]:                         fe80::cf7f:bfe6:b1fb:6078/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::7e4c:a5ff:fe24:ddfc
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a02:c7d:51b5:ee00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fd36:554f:9232::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd36:554f:9232:0:7e4c:a5ff:fe24:ddfc

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         94:65:2D:6F:EE:06
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         94:65:2D:6F:EE:06
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

Skype seems to fail the same way and I can also fix by deleting ~/.config/skypeforlinux, although it eventually fails again. My guess is a failing dns name resolution. My bet is chromium, chrome and skype use the same method that firefox does not and that fails (and that is somehow dependent on local settings stored until they are removed). How can I make sure? Perhaps I can test it by deleting only the files responsible for it in ~/.config/chromium but which one(s) are they?

Comment: Skype seems to fail the same way and I can also fix by deleting `~/.config/skypeforlinux`, although it eventually fails again. My guess is a failing dns name resolution. My bet is chromium, chrome and skype use the same method that firefox does not and that fails (and that is somehow dependent on local settings stored until they are removed). How can I make sure? Perhaps I can test it by deleting only the files responsible for it in `~/.config/chromium` but which one(s) are they?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of ideas if you don't use a network proxy.